# Replace double String.Format with string interpolation

Tags: c#, .net, string.format, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

I tried to migrate a line of code that uses `String.Format` twice to the new .NET Framework 6 string interpolation feature but until now I was not successfull.

```
var result = String.Format(String.Format("{{0:{0}}}{1}", 
    strFormat, withUnit ? " Kb" : String.Empty), 
    (double)fileSize / FileSizeConstant.KO);
```

A working example could be:

```
var result = String.Format(String.Format("{{0:{0}}}{1}", 
   "N2", " Kb"), 1000000000 / 1048576D);
```

which outputs: 953,67 Kb

Is that possible or do we need to use the old construct for this special case?

Comment: Mine is not an answer, but I'd discourage anyone (me firstly) to put tons of ops in the same line. It's just matter of readability, but then maybe the interpolation can succeed.

Comment: It's probably not possible with string interpolation since you're injecting a format string (via `strFormat`).  Although it _could_ be simplified as Mario suggests to make it more readable.

Comment: you can turn the inner string.format to string interpolation but its not possible for the outer string.format. since the given string is variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue lies in `strFormat` variable, you can't put it as format specifier like this `"{((double)fileSize/FileSizeConstant.KO):strFormat}"`  because colon format specifier is not a part of interpolation expression and thus is not evaluated into string literal `N2`. From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160(v=vs.140).aspx):

> The structure of an interpolated string is as follows:
>  
>   `$"<text> { <interpolation-expression> <optional-comma-field-width> <optional-colon-format> } <text> ... } "`

You can make format as a part of expression by passing it to [`double.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
$"{((double)fileSize/FileSizeConstant.KO).ToString(strFormat)}{(withUnit?" Kb":string.Empty)}";
```